# Javascript, delete array element by numeric key and leave no empty value

Tags: javascript

Hello I have an array

```
window["fancyHistory"] = [window.location.pathname];
```

That array is updated by another function which ads strings (urls) to that array using numeric keys, usually they ingresses like 1,2,3... but sometimes they may appear not as progression but still a number.

There is another function which must delete some of that keys, usually it is the last one. I tried pop(), delete(key), something like

```
for (var key in window.fancyHistory) {
    if (key == instance.id) {
        window.fancyHistory.splice(key, 1);
    }
}
```

or

```
window.fancyHistory = window.fancyHistory.splice( window.fancyHistory.length - instance.id);
```

Anyway I have empty elements in this array, so I have to look for last non empty element by

```
var index = window.fancyHistory.length;

while (index-- && !window.fancyHistory[index]);
```

Is there more adequate solution which also works? I don't understand why it leaves empty keys in my array despite many solutions such as splice which are written in the Internet ages ago, isn't that because of it window. array?

Comment: can you create a working snippet demonstrating your issue?

Comment: why window as object?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking. You've asked if your code at the end is an efficient way to find the last non-empty entry (it is), but also you've asked *why* you're getting empty entries. What is your actual question? If the latter, we need a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, the code above isn't sufficient for us to help you.

Comment: I use FancyBox to navigate through some pages, I keep history in this array window["fancyHistory"] = [window.location.pathname]; some events trigger fancybox to open and it ads history entries, in order to keep navigation through pages I have that window["fancyHistory"] which is updated when fancybox is open, when it is closed i have to delete either last entry either couple of entries starting with specific elements. I tried delete and splice by my array still contains empty elements

Comment: for example ["/", empty × 2, "/catalog/bla-bla-bla/", empty], that is result of delete. I want to get rid of empty elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a filter to remove items from an array. It doesn't leave any empty/undefined/null elements.

```
window.fancyHistory = window.fancyHistory.filter( key => key!==instance.id )
```

This filters out every key that matches `instance.id`.

But for the record, if you have an array with some undefined or null elements, you can remove them this way :

```
myArray = myArray.filter( element => !!element )
```

If `element` is undefined, then `!element` is true and `!!element` is false, therefore it will be removed.

Comment: OMG. Thank you. That is why I hate that language, its sintax and behavior are unpredictable I tried window.fancyHistory.filter(function(n){ return n != ""  }); and window.fancyHistory.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined  }); it gave no good

Comment: Does it work in all browsers including mobile ones? That constructions (!!) often cause troubles in mobile devices

Comment: It works in iOS and Android, so I think it has to work in WP as well. Thanks once again.

Comment: No, I think `!!` is very standard JS. I'm happy you found my answer helpful :)

Comment: I have experienced that some features which were described in ES6 did not work in all devices correctly. It is still the same problem as at was 00-s, when they update standard it may take couple of years to make it work correctly everywhere

Comment: In case in anyone will try => construction, please have in mind that it does not work in iPad 2, it breaks all javascript implementation on a device. If you need iPad 2 support you need another solution.

Comment: Useful links : https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ and https://caniuse.com/#search=ES6